# how to display data for a specific month in a table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

is it possible to display the data on which column month of the table?
below is the sample dashboard to achieve
[image]

and this is my DB
[image]

currently this is my dashboard. I want to align the data base on the period in the DB.
[image]

what should be my tboby look like to achieve the desired dashboard

this is my index html

```
<div class="w3-container w3-padding-64 w3-theme-l5">
<div class="w3-padding-16"><span class="w3-xlarge w3-border-purple w3-bottombar">COUNT PER BUSINESS UNIT</span></div>
<div>
    <table id="businessUnit-tbl" class="table table-bordered display nowrap">
        <thead>
            <tr style="/*color:white;*/ align-content:center">
                <td>MONTH</td>
            </tr>
            <tr @*style="color:white"*@>
                <td>Business Unit</td>
                <td id="jan">January</td>
                <td id="feb">February</td>
                <td id="mar">March</td>
                <td id="apr">April</td>
                <td id="may">May</td>
                <td id="june">June</td>
                <td id="july">July</td>
                <td id="aug">August</td>
                <td id="sept">September</td>
                <td id="oct">October</td>
                <td id="nov">November</td>
                <td id="dec">December</td>
                <td id="total">Total</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding of the topic, I suggest leaving tbody blank and trying to fill it with javascript

```
// append column to the HTML table
function appendColumn() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('my-table'), // table reference
        i;
    // open loop for each row and append cell
    for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
        createCell(tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Ali, I have a partial html for tbody where it loops the data that it gets from my view table. as much as possible i want my months to be static